# Scanning on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, scanner

I am at a loss as to how to do this. I want to scan a document from my all-in-one printer. I do not have the proprietary bundled printer / scanner software installed from the printer company.

What is the *easiest* way to natively scan something from Windows 10 regardless of what it is?

Comment: some AIO solutions can scan documents and share them over LAN or internet. check if yours has that feature or enhance your question with printer and network information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Windows 10 brings a Microsoft in-house [scanning app](http://www.windows10update.com/2015/03/new-scanner-app-in-windows-10-build-10036/).

[image]

**Personally, I prefer the [Windows Fax and Scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Fax_and_Scan) application. If you can't find it on your Windows 10 computer, make sure that you have installed this feature. Look down!**

[image]

In both ways you have to [install the scanner (drivers)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/install-a-scanner) before you can start to use the this applications.

Comment: Thanks! I just did an clean upgrade for someone and this app is not visible. I will install it from the store now

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to go to the website of the printer manufacturer, and download and install their proprietary scanner software.